# ScrollWindowEx throws ArgumentError

Tags: python, winapi

I have a window that has a bunch of buttons. When the buttons exceed the window's height, I want to have a scroll bar, but when I tried to implement it, it threw ArgumentError, but the Windows API says that values can be Null (that is what I am doing). This is the function I am talking about: [ScrollWindowEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-scrollwindowex). If you want to run my code in your machine, this is [user32.py](https://gist.github.com/aryan-debug/3b025cde064945fe63dd729a67bc7cbb)

Edit: This is the error message: `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 4: <class 'TypeError'>: expected RECT instance instead of NoneType`

And this is main.py:

```
from os import listdir
from user32 import *
from button import Button
from pathlib import Path

hInst = windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(0)
buttons = []

BTN_WIDTH = 300
BTN_HEIGHT = 100
LINES = 28

def window_proc(hwnd: HWND, umsg: UINT, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT:
    si = SCROLLINFO()
    si_pointer = pointer(si)
    match umsg:
        case WindowMessage.CREATE:
            create_list_of_buttons(get_files(), hwnd)
        case WindowMessage.DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0)
            return 0
        
        case WindowMessage.SIZE:
            height = (HIWORD(lparam))
            width = (LOWORD(lparam))

            si.cbSize = sizeof(si)
            si.fMask = ScrollInfoMessage.RANGE | ScrollInfoMessage.PAGE
            si.nMin = 0
            si.nMax = LINES
            si.nPage = int(height.value) // BTN_HEIGHT;
            SetScrollInfo(hwnd, ScrollBarConstants.VERT, si_pointer, True)

        case WindowMessage.COMMAND:
            if wparam >= 100:
                btn_clicked = ([button for button in buttons if button.hMenu == wparam])
                filename = btn_clicked[0].btn_text
                print(filename)
        case WindowMessage.VSCROLL:
            si.cbSize = sizeof(si)
            si.fMask = ScrollInfoMessage.ALL
            GetScrollInfo(hwnd, ScrollBarConstants.VERT, si_pointer)

            yPos = si.nPos
            print(LOWORD(wparam).value)
            match LOWORD(wparam).value:
                case ScrollBarCommands.LINEUP:
                    si.nPos -= 1
                case ScrollBarCommands.THUMBTRACK:
                    print(si.nPos)
                    si.nPos = si.nTrackPos
                    print(si.nPos)

            si.fMask = ScrollInfoMessage.POS
            SetScrollInfo(hwnd, ScrollBarConstants.VERT, si_pointer, True)
            GetScrollInfo(hwnd, ScrollBarConstants.VERT, si_pointer)
            if(si.nPos != yPos):
                # This line causes the error
                ScrollWindowEx(hwnd, 0, yPos - si.nPos, None, None, None, None, 0x0010)
                UpdateWindow(hwnd)

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, umsg, wparam, lparam)


def create_window(className, windowName):
    wnd_main = CreateWindowExW(
        0,
        className,
        windowName,
        WindowStyles.OVERLAPPED
        | WindowStyles.CAPTION
        | WindowStyles.SYSMENU
        | WindowStyles.THICKFRAME
        | WindowStyles.MINIMIZEBOX
        | WindowStyles.MAXIMIZEBOX
        | WindowStyles.CAPTION
        | WindowStyles.VSCROLL,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        600,
        600,
        0,
        0,
        hInst,
        0,
    )
    if not wnd_main:
        print("Window Creation Falid: ", GetLastError())
        return
    return wnd_main


def get_files():
    folder_path = Path(__file__).parent / "log"
    return [file for file in listdir(folder_path) if file.endswith(".txt")]

def create_list_of_buttons(filenames: list[str], parent_window):
    """
    Makes a list of button that have the file's name as their heading
    """
    x, y = 0, 0
    for button_id, filename in enumerate(filenames, 100):
        button = Button(filename, x, y, BTN_WIDTH, BTN_HEIGHT, parent_window, button_id)
        button.create_button()
        buttons.append(button)
        y += BTN_HEIGHT

    return buttons




def main():
    wclassName = ctypes.c_wchar_p("My")
    wname = ctypes.c_wchar_p("Left")
    wndClass = WNDCLASSEXW()
    wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW)
    wndClass.style = ClassStyles.HREDRAW | ClassStyles.VREDRAW
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WNDPROC(window_proc)
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0
    wndClass.hInstance = hInst
    wndClass.hIcon = 0
    wndClass.hCursor = 0
    wndClass.hBrush = windll.gdi32.GetStockObject(0)
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = 0
    wndClass.lpszClassName = wclassName
    wndClass.hIconSm = 0

    RegisterClassExW(byref(wndClass))
    wnd_main = create_window(wclassName, wname)
    ShowWindow(wnd_main, 5)
    UpdateWindow(wnd_main)

    msg = MSG()
    lpmsg = pointer(msg)

    while (GetMessageW(lpmsg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0:
        TranslateMessage(lpmsg)
        DispatchMessageW(lpmsg)


main()
```

Comment: I guess it's an error in the definition of that function in Python, as you're right - the docs do say it can be null. If it is null the entire client area is scrolled, so you should be able to get the same effect by passing it the address of a RECT structure representing the entire client area (which you can get using GetClientRect).

Comment: When I make a RECT for the 4th argument, it tells me to make one for 5th argument as well, but I don't know what I should write there. I tried RECT(0, 0, 0, 0) for the 5th argument and when I scrolled, everything disappeared except the scrollbar.

Comment: You should be able to give it the same rectangle.

Comment: My window's size is 600x600. So, I make RECT(0, 0, 600, 600) for both 4th and 5th argument, but everything disappears again when I scroll.